# single-post.php not working on live WordPress site?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a file called `single-post.php` to add some styling to all the blog posts.

In XAMPP `localhost` the blog posts pages work as normal. However on the live website I cannot click into the blog posts.

I've used both `single-post.php` and `single.php` to see which one works. Same problem.

Here is the folder structure:

[image]

Here is the blog link (try clicking a post to see what I mean): http://radian3.com/blog/

Which template page are we suppose to use to edit blog posts?

Comment: single.php is the template for posts. You do not need to write single-post.php However if you are still confused you can use a plugin that shows which template is being used on any page.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know WP supports single.php in stead of single-post.php in their codex. Please check the codex section in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default post, so you no need to create single-post.php file, simply use only single.php

How many posts you will add in post, all will show in single.php only.

If you are create custom post like hotel, so you need to create file name as single-hotel.php.